# How to get hold of current index when using Maps.uniqueIndex

Tags: java, guava

We have a List of items: `List<X>`
from this List, we would like to create `Map<F(X), X>`

using Guava `com.google.common.collect`,
there is `Maps.uniqueIndex` method, which takes a List as an input and
allows us to apply a function to elements.

this is all great. for example:

```
List<File> to Map<String, File>

mapOfFileNames = Maps.uniqueIndex(fileList, new Function<File, String>() {
            @Override
            public String apply(@Nullable File input) {
                return input.getName();
            }
        });
```

my question is, how we can get hold of **position** of *the current Item* (index) in the List,
when using `Maps.uniqueIndex`

for example, to convert `List<File> to Map<Integer, File>`
I would like keys to be the position of File element in the List.
therefore I need to get access to the index of the current element.

do you know how this can be possible ?

Thank You

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why do you want to do this? I don't really see the usefulness of it, given that you can do lookups in a `List` by index anyway. Getting the index of the input item in the `Function` would be wasteful because you'd have to do an `indexOf` for each item. If you really want to do this, I'd say just do:

```
List<File> list = ...
Map<Integer, File> map = Maps.newHashMap();
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
  map.put(i, list.get(i));
}
```

On a related note, all `ImmutableCollection`s have an `asList()` view, which could allow you to do index-based lookup on any `ImmutableMap`. `Maps.uniqueIndex` also preserves the order from the original collection. Using your example:

```
ImmutableMap<String, File> mapOfFileNames = Maps.uniqueIndex(...);
/*
 * The entry containing the file that was at index 5 in the original list
 * and its filename.
 */
Map.Entry<String, File> entry = mapOfFileNames.entrySet().asList().get(5);
```